# Checking for certain special characters in a string using regex

Tags: regex

I have a username field in which I do not want certain characters like / \ ? # tab newline .
Is there any regex pattern that I can use for this or any pattern in which I can pass in certain characters that I do now want.Sorry not very familiar with Regex so asking directly.

This regex is not working for me *[^!@%~?:#$%^&*()0']* .I read that using ^ and then the characters check means we do not want these characters.Is there something wrong with this regex.WHen using with jquery validation plugin it is throwing an error.

Thanks

Comment: What a good time to [become familiar](http://www.regular-expressions.info/)!

Comment: What you probably need is a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html), although you will have to define your problem more precisely. Do you only want to disallow those few characters and allow everything else?

Comment: Yes I just want a few characters to be disallowed something like "^(?=#*\/){1,15}$" in which I want to disallow the characters inside the bracket and make the username just 15 characters long.But this regex is not working properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
/^[^!@%~?:#$%^&()0']{1,15}$/.test(str);
```

Examples:

```
/^[^!@%~?:#$%^&()0']{1,15}$/.test("a");                // true
/^[^!@%~?:#$%^&()0']{1,15}$/.test("fooBar");           // true
/^[^!@%~?:#$%^&()0']{1,15}$/.test("a!b");              // false
/^[^!@%~?:#$%^&()0']{1,15}$/.test("tooLoooooooooong"); // false
```